# Difficulty reading .tab file in R due to newline and tab not being recognized properly

Tags: r, newline, delimiter

I am trying to read in a .tab file in R and while I am able to read the file, I am getting strange results due to what appears to be hidden tab or newline characters.

```
data<-read.table("data.tab",header=TRUE,sep="\t",fill=TRUE)
```

The first two lines appear fine but the third line appears like

`...column6val column7val\tcolumn8val\ncolumn1val\...`

Where the column1val represents the first column for what should be the 4th line

So it appears to me like the tab between the 7th and 8th columns isn't being read correctly and instead just shows up as \t for some reason?

I can't provide the data as it is confidential, however in the 7th column of line 3 the value contains "it's". When I removed the appostrophe the data is then read correctly.

Comment: To answer this question we need to know what the content of the data.tab file is. Can you edit your answer to provide the content of the file (e.g. open it with an editor) or provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: The data is confidential, I can't provide it, and if I edit the data (delete the confidential part and replace with some dummy data) the problem disappears...

Comment: Sounds like you might have some unbalanced quotes in the file. We're really need to see a reproducible example to know for sure what's going on.

Comment: I edited the question with a bit more information, the line in question has a value that contains an apostrophe that if I remove solves the problem, but I am not sure why

Comment: If you are aren't expecting any column to contain quoted data, then set `quote=""` when you call `read.table`

Comment: What do you mean by quoted data? quote="" works but I dont really understand why

Comment: You can inspect the actual character values in R with `readChar("data.tab", 300)`. Replace the 300 with whatever number gets you to the third line.  Then you'll see where the newline and tab characters are.  If you still need help, replace the confidential stuff with random words, keep the spacing, and use it in your question's example.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, needed to include quote="" in my read.table call